# spring boot:edit a row in a table using modal form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, modal-dialog, thymeleaf

I'm a beginner in spring boot so please pardon my ignorance.
I have this table:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" id="dataTable" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Service code</th>
        <th>description</th>
        <th>answer</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="appel : ${list}">
        <td th:text="${appel.id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${appel.serviceCode}"></td>
        <td th:text="${appel.description}"></td>
        <td th:text="${appel.answer}"></td>
        <td><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalHorizontal" class="btn1">Edit</button></td>
        <td><a th:href="@{/appel/delete/{id}(id=${appel.id})}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this table is filled with data from database expet for the column "answer" it's always empty
when I click the button "edit" this form appear to fill the column "answer" and save it in the table "service" that have the appropriate id 
[image]

I'm working with spring boot and I didn't know how to insert the answer to database in the row  with the same id please any ideas?

Comment: as you are a beginner may I suggest try using this library https://github.com/ArslanAnjum/angularSpringApi. Clone the repo to get a working project sample. it uses spring data rest, jsp, angular js and materialize css

Comment: i really appreciate your help but i have to do this project using this tools and i want so far so i can't change from thymeleaf to jsp and angular but could you suggest another methode to fill in the answer column and send it to database.thank you in advance

Comment: You can review this tutorial it explains how  to use angular js with rest api's created with spring boot and mvc.  http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-rest-api-example/